# How do I run a background service written in MONO?

Tags: debian, boot, mono, services

I need the service to automatically start upon boot, it does not require console access for a start. Ofcause it would be nice to be able to produce some output for logging/debugging/stats. But for now, I just need a "TCP listener" that runs in the background, written in C#/mono.

Anyone in here able to show me how you install a service in Debian?

So this program isnt visible, its just like a "daemon" or cron perhaps. Cant figure out where to put it and how to initiate it.

Comment: cron *is* a daemon ;)

Comment: How did you get on with this? What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 6):

Create an init.d script to run your application

you can run the mono service in linux OS by using the command 
mono-service [options] program.exe call this from an init.d sript

Check this man page for more details about running mono service on linux
http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service

Comment: cool will try to check that out

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to write a debian style sysv init script (see `/etc/init.d/README`), you can just append a line to `/etc/rc.local`, eg:

```
/full/path/to/myprogram &
```

The full path is necessary as $PATH may not be properly set for rc.local when it is run at boot (but it will be for "myprogram").

The `&` just backgrounds the process, allowing rc.local to continue and exit.  "myprogram" is now running *owned by root*.  That may be desirable if you want to open a low number privileged (server) port at start-up; for security the process should subsequently switch (effective) user id (euid/uid).

If you don't need root privileges at all:

```
/bin/su [user] -c /full/path/to/myprogram &
```

Comment: aha! interesting too! going to check tomorrow too.

Answer (score 1):

you can create **init.d** script and use **start-stop-daemon** together with **nohup** to start your app in the background.
Here is an example with [kestrel web server](http://druss.co/2015/06/run-kestrel-in-the-background/) (which is eventually run with mono). Just change *\"$DNXRUNTIME\" kestrel > \"$LOGFILE\"* to your command line.